# Transitioning an HTML <dialog> on open using Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to animate the opening of a  element using Tailwind CSS. The [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#open-closed-state) suggests this is the right way to add a fade-in, but it seems that the `[open]` selector must not be present when the dialog is not open, so it doesn't transition from opacity 0 to 100, it simply goes straight to 100. Is there a better/different/right way to do this?

```
<dialog id="myDialog" class="transition-opacity duration-1000 opacity-0 open:opacity-100">
  <p>Hello, world</p>
  <form method="dialog">
    <button>Close</button>
  </form>
</dialog>

<button onclick="openDialog()">Open dialog</button>

<script>
function openDialog() {
  document.getElementById("myDialog").showModal();
}
</script>
```

https://codepen.io/rytrose/pen/yLKNJRo

Answer (score 2):

For me, the best solution I could find was to add a custom animation on `tailwind.config.js` to then apply that animation on the open state.

Let's say I want to change the scale from 0 to 1 when opening the modal. For that I would do:

**tailwind.config.js**

```
...

theme: {
        extend: {
            animation: {
                modalf: "modalf 0.15s ease-in-out",
            },
            keyframes: {
                modalf: {
                    "0%": { transform: "scale(0)" },
                    "100%": { transform: "scale(1)" },
                },
            },
        },
    },

...
```

**index.html**

```
<dialog class="other classes... open:animate-modalf">
...
</dialog>
```

With that, the animation should happen when the `open` state is present on the `dialog` tag itself. Of course, this would also work if you're using `modal.showModal()` as well since it still adds the `open` property to the `dialog`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do the same, but no luck. My solution was to use react-transition-group. Example (using React):

```html
<CSSTransition
      in={isOpen}
      appear
      classNames={{
        enter: 'opacity-0 backdrop:opacity-0',
        enterDone: 'opacity-100 backdrop:opacity-80',
        exitDone: 'opacity-0 backdrop:opacity-0',
      }}
    >
      <dialog
        className="rounded-lg p-0 shadow transition backdrop:bg-neutral-900 backdrop:opacity-80 backdrop:transition"
        ref={modalRef}
      >
        <button className="absolute top-0 right-1" onClick={onClose}>
          x
        </button>
        {children}
      </dialog>
    </CSSTransition>
```